# 404 for custom post link on IIS with URL Rewrite Module

Tags: php, wordpress, windows, iis, url-rewriting

I need to use IIS to develop the new WordPress site. After reading a lot of articles, I installed the URL Rewrite Module on IIS (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

My site structure is:
localhost/projectname/projectcms/

I set the WordPress URL on cms as:
http://localhost/projectname/projectcms

And the wordpress was installed inside the projectcms folder.

The site URL as:
http://localhost/projectname

Also, I customize the post link as:
http://localhost/projectname/% category%/%year%/%postname%/

(no space between "%" and "c")

However, those pages display 404 errors.

What is the rewrite rule I need to set on the URL Rewrite Module in order to make those links work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to redirect from `http://localhost/projectname` to `http://localhost/projectname/% category%/%year%/%postname%/`? if so, you can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^projectname$" />           
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/projectname/% category%/%year%/%postname%/" />
</rule>
```